# C#: Is there a difference between (float) (x / y) and x / (float) y?

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point

I am wondering if the following expressions are equivalent (In C#):

```
float x = ... ;
int y = ... ;

var result = (float) (x / y);

Versus:

var result = x / (float)y;
```

Where can i read more about this specific topic?

What i am interested in is:

1. Will these always produce the same result?
2. Does one option perform more efficiently than the other?

Comment: I've heard there is that one author who wrote a book about C#.

Comment: You can read more at MSDN and the C# specification.

Comment: Was there a helpful answer? If so, please feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they will behave the same way. In fact, you can just use:

```
var result = x / y;
```

or

```
float result = x / y;
```

Section 7.8.2 of the C# 4 spec shows which division operators are avaiable - and there's no `float operator /(float, int)` operator. Instead, the C# compiler uses the implicit conversion from `int` to `float`, and uses the `float operator /(float, float)` operator.

This is just normal operator overload resolution (spec section 7.3.4) and implicit numeric conversions (spec section 6.1.2).

When in doubt consult the spec. I have a [web page with links to the different versions](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx); the C# 5 spec is bundled with VS 2012 but there's no separate download for it right now.

Comment: Is there any significant different between an implicit conversion (method call?) to the casting (which i am not sure but may involve a method call as well?)

Comment: @lysergic-acid: No, there's no method call involved here. It's just the difference between the conversion being implicit and explicit, which is just a matter of source code (given that it's the same conversion in both cases).

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference at all. The resulting IL code is identical:

Here's what the IL Disassembler returns for both variants:

```
// Code size       16 (0x10)
.maxstack  2
.locals init ([0] float32 x,
         [1] int32 y,
         [2] float32 result)
IL_0000:  nop
IL_0001:  ldc.r4     1.5
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.1
IL_0008:  stloc.1
IL_0009:  ldloc.0
IL_000a:  ldloc.1
IL_000b:  conv.r4
IL_000c:  div
IL_000d:  conv.r4
IL_000e:  stloc.2
IL_000f:  ret
```